# Angular JS get alert when change cursor between two textfields

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, onchange

I have two text fields I wanna get alert when moved cursor from one field to another after completion of entering some text. How can I achieve it in angular JS? I tried [`ng-change`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) but it's getting alert when I enters second letter in first field only.

HTML:

```
               <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class=" "></span><span
                        class="input-text">Number of Working Days</span></span> <input
                        type="text" class="form-control " id="workingDays"
                        ng-model="workingDays" ng-change="updateDays();" />
                </div>
```

JS:

```
$scope.updateDays = function() {
alert('Got an alert');
};
```

Here I wanna update rows based on the after entering days, but I am getting when I was enter second number.

Thank you..
Any reference link or comment will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I correctly understood, what you want, so you can use [**ngBlur**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBlur) directive.

THis is [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/9417/) with example.

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <span> field 1</span> 
  <input type="text" ng-model="field1" ng-blur="leftCursor()">

  <span> field 1</span> 
  <input type="text" ng-model="field2">
</div>

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.leftCursor = function(){
        alert('Cursor has left current field!');
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [`ng-blur`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBlur), not `ng-change`:

> The blur event is fired when an element has lost focus.
>   The main difference between this event and focusout is that only the latter bubbles.

(source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/blur)

Since you want to alert when the user moves from first to second field, you need to attach `ng-blur` to the first field so it fires before the second field gets focus.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you want to do

[`ng-mouseover`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngMouseenter) when the cursor is over the element

[`ng-focus`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngFocus) when the element has focus (when you click on the input it get focus)

[`ng-blur`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBlur) when the element loses focus (when you click on other elements the focused one lose focus and triggers the blur event)

From your description seems that you need to use `ng-blur` and validate the value when the input has lost focus.